# It is possible to mock a MQTT broker in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, mqtt, paho

I want to make a unit test for a Mqtt client module in Android Studio, because i want to send data from an Android Device to PC, but i don't know how to test that without a real server, i'm using paho library. There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the paho library to mock a broker, but there is moquette broker (https://github.com/moquette-io/moquette) which you might be able to use to embed a broker in an existing Java app

Comment: Does anyone know where we can download the listener from?
the given binaryTray link in the README file is dead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is easy to perform local offline tests while developing with Android Studio and Android Emulator at your Mac, Linux or Windows computer -

First install [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/download/) and run the broker at the localhost (on Windows just double click the `mosquitto.exe`, on Linux/Mac run `./mosquitto` in Terminal window).

Then open another Terminal window and subscribe to all topics by running:

```
./mosquito_sub -v -t "#"
```

Or on Windows in cmd window:

```
mosquito_sub.exe -v -t "#"
```

Finally in your Java source code change the URL when running in the emulator:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return (Build.PRODUCT != null && Build.PRODUCT.toLowerCase().contains("sdk")) ||
            (Build.MODEL != null && Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("sdk"));
}

private static final String BROKER_URL = 
    isEmulator() ? "tcp://10.0.2.2/" : "tcp://test.mosquitto.org/";
```

Comment: It is possible to use "mosquitto_sub" using java code?

Comment: You can run any program from Java by using [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: I will change my question, is there a java api to create a mqtt broker?